# Get all rows until today

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get all rows from my table unitll today, I see somwhere to accomplish such query users use `FROM_UNIXTIME(mytimestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` but it's not working correctly, any ideas?

Comment: What error do you get? How does it not work correctly?

Comment: @JohnConde I don't get any error - It's not show me a correct result, e.g it's show me a row which is added today!

Comment: You want to change the `<=` to `<` and get rid of the `INTERVAL 1 DAY`, also the format string is unnecessary.

Comment: @BobKaufman yeah you're right I will edit the OP, Yes I have timestamp cloumn in my table.

Comment: @TiiJ7 Can you post me an example?

Comment: I didn't notice the interval at first. But you could try this in your `WHERE` clause: `mytimestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())` (assuming your `mytimestamp` is a UNIX timestamp column.

Comment: @TiiJ7 The problem is my timestamp column is an integer column instead of UNIX timestamp column.

Comment: UNIX timestamps are 32bit integers. I should have said an `INT` column with UNIX timestamp values

Comment: @TiiJ7 tried but still it's show me a incorrect result!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of '<=' just try '<' wihtout '- INTERVAL 1 DAY'. That might solve the problem.

Comment: The problem is still persist!